# OpenAPI query parameter description not set to text box as placeholder

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I have used description to add details for query parameter like

```
"parameters": [                 
                {
                    "name": "role",
                    "in": "query",
                    "required": true,
                    "schema": {
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    "description": "This is test description to reproduce placeholder not fit to textbox"                       
                }]
```

When I load openapi.json to swagger it shows description as well as in text box placeholder. Is there any way to add separate text for placeholder or any way to fix show all text in placeholder? Here text is stripped

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the parameter has an `example` or `default` value (or `x-example` in OpenAPI 2.0), Swagger UI will use this value as a placeholder instead.

[image: Swagger UI uses the parameter's example value as an input placeholder]

Otherwise, as you've noticed, the placeholder text will be the same as the parameter's `description`.

There's an existing feature request to remove or improve the default placeholder text:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/3920

Answer (score 0):

You can always override methods from the auto-openapi library.
Instead of **default** key, you can use **placeholder** property to not conflict with validator's schema.
In case of MoleculerJS here's how you can do :

1. Override method **getTypeAndExample** , add one more conditional check for key placeholder.
   `if (node.placeholder) {  out.example = node.placeholder; }`
2. It may require certain enum's, paste it from the library or copy from below, `const NODE_TYPES = { boolean: "boolean", number: "number", date: "date", uuid: "uuid", email: "email", url: "url", string: "string", enum: "enum", }`
3. Use `placeholder:"<value>"` in prop's of your schema to only populate values to try in swagger UI.