# API-Platform Swagger UI parameter description also shows in input field

Tags: symfony, swagger-ui, api-platform.com

Adding a custom description to a parameter on Swagger causes that description to be also included as part of the `<input>` placeholder.

[image: input error]

The code that generates this:

```
                   new Parameter(
                        name: 'siren', 
                        description: "<p>Recherche par <code>siren</code>.</p>",
                        schema: ['type' => 'string'], 
                        in: 'query', 
                        required: false,
                    ), 
                    new Parameter(
                        name: 'raison_sociale_deduite', 
                        description: "Recherche par `raison sociale deduite`",
                        schema: ['type' => 'string'], 
                        in: 'query', 
                        required: false
```

So it does not matter if I place that with HTML or MarkUp, it will end up bleeding into the input placeholder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? -- [OpenAPI query parameter description set to text box as placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69481440/113116)